# Why I can drag one view to left, right, top, down in ScrollView?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have 3 views in ScrollView. I don't understand about it because I want to scroll left to right or right to left but it can allow me to drag these view to top or down or right or left. I also use some code as below but it does't work.

```
scrollView.pagingEnabled=YES;
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=NO;
scrollView.scrollsToTop=NO;
```

are there any code to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set contentSize of ScrollView and while setting it set height accordingly to your view which are inside the scrollview.

It'll solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I also set contenSize of ScrollView according my view but It doesn't work. scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(numberofPage*self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

Comment: No. You should set height as per your view's height. i.e. Static height or highest height of the view resides in scrollview. I hope it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Set your scrollView content size like:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(allviewstotalwidth,requiredHeight);// For eg:CGSizeMake(320+320+320,460);
```